# Intellij+Gradle+JUnit5 problem - Cannot find any tests in IDE, in gradle wrapper everything is fine

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, junit

When I trying to run up my JUnit tests in Intellij, I getting an error about missing class. When I am doing it directly from gradle wrapper, everything is okay.

This is a full description of error:

```
wrz 02, 2019 11:41:28 AM org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher handleThrowable
WARNING: TestEngine with ID 'junit-jupiter' failed to discover tests
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/platform/engine/support/discovery/SelectorResolver
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.JupiterTestEngine.discover(JupiterTestEngine.java:69)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discoverEngineRoot(DefaultLauncher.java:168)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discoverRoot(DefaultLauncher.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.processAllTestClasses(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:102)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.access$000(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:82)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.stop(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:78)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:61)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.stop(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.stop(TestWorker.java:132)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:175)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:404)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.junit.platform.engine.support.discovery.SelectorResolver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 33 more

wrz 02, 2019 11:41:28 AM org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher handleThrowable
WARNING: TestEngine with ID 'junit-vintage' failed to discover tests
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/platform/engine/support/discovery/SelectorResolver
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.discover(VintageTestEngine.java:62)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discoverEngineRoot(DefaultLauncher.java:168)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discoverRoot(DefaultLauncher.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.processAllTestClasses(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:102)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.access$000(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:82)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.stop(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:78)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:61)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.stop(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.stop(TestWorker.java:132)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:175)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:404)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.junit.platform.engine.support.discovery.SelectorResolver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 33 more
```

```
plugins {
  id "org.sonarqube" version "2.6"
  id "com.jfrog.artifactory" version "4.8.1"
  id 'net.researchgate.release' version '2.6.0'
}

// Common dependencies version
ext {
  assertjVersion = '3.8.0'
  commonsLangVersion = '3.7'
  hibernateValidatorVersion = '6.0.14.Final'
  jacksonVersion = '2.9.9'
  keycloakVersion = '6.0.1'
  junitVersion = '5.5.1'
  lombokVersion = '1.18.4'
  mockitoVersion = '2.23.0+'
  springBootVersion = '2.1.0.RELEASE'
  springVersion = '5.1.4.RELEASE'
  springDependencyManagementVersion = '1.0.5.RELEASE'
  springCloudSleuthVersion = '2.1.0.RELEASE'
}

  // Plugins
  apply plugin: 'jacoco'
  apply plugin: 'java-library'
  apply plugin: 'idea'

  // Properties
  group = "${mainGroupId}"
  sourceCompatibility = 1.8
  targetCompatibility = 1.8

  // Repositories
  repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    jcenter()
  }

  tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = "UTF-8"
  }

  // Dependencies
  dependencies {
    testImplementation group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-core', version: mockitoVersion
    testImplementation group: 'org.assertj', name: 'assertj-core', version: assertjVersion

    testImplementation group: 'org.junit.jupiter', name: 'junit-jupiter-api', version: junitVersion
    testImplementation group: 'org.junit.jupiter', name: 'junit-jupiter-engine', version: junitVersion
    testImplementation group: 'org.junit.vintage', name: 'junit-vintage-engine', version: junitVersion
  }

  test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
  }

  task cleanUp(type: Delete) {
    delete 'build', 'out'
  }

  clean.doLast { cleanUp }
}
```

Version of Intellij:

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.1 (Ultimate Edition)
Build #IU-192.6262.58, built on August 20, 2019
Runtime version: 11.0.3+12-b304.39 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Linux 4.15.0-58-generic
GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
Memory: 4029M
Cores: 8
Registry: ide.balloon.shadow.size=0
Non-Bundled Plugins: CMD Support, GrepConsole, Lombook Plugin, com.alayouni.ansiHighlight, com.intellij.ideolog, de.timon.schelling.interesting.theme, io.codearte.props2yaml, GradleDependenciesHelper
```

I've done everything what I already know(Invalidate cache, removing build/out directory, reconfiguring project, trying on fresh instance of project).

Please help.
Thanks in advance,
Igor.

Comment: it seems it is missing some JUnit classes. just add a dependency to get them.

Comment: @Stultuske I've updated a question by a gradle build. Can you look at it?

Comment: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/platform/engine/support/discovery/SelectorResolver

Comment: I think this is not dependency problem, because from pure gradle wrapper everything is fine. Problem is when I am trying to run it by the Intellij IDE gradle plugin.

Comment: it's a class from the platform-engine, I don't see you importing that dependency anywhere

Comment: Unfortunately, that takes no effect.

Comment: I can not reproduce the problem with given build.gradle file. Make sure there are no other conflicting dependencies in classpath. Re-generate project by re-importing it in IDE: File | New | Project from Existing Sources. Make also source you are running proper JUnit5 test class. Also try re-download IDE and re-install into new empty directory.

Comment: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` means that you have that lib but in incorrect version. You need to figure out what dependency in your gradle override your junit lib.

Comment: Got to Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle. What is set for "Run tests using"?

Comment: I solved this. This is more complex problem that I thought. This error occurs, when there is no junit-platform dependencies as @Stultuske mentioned. But thats not all. You have to look on your gradle version, and look that it fits to your junit. My gradle 5.5+ occurs this problem. I downgraded it to 5.2.1, and downgraded junit to 5.2.0, and its worked. Also there is problem when you mixing vintage and normal junit dependencies and tests. You have just to experiment with proper configuration. I hope this answer will help you in any way. Cheers! :)